# Migrating from VS2005 to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, migration

After migrating a project from VS 2005 to VS 2010, we got the following errors related to include fils of Visual Studio, can anyone provide inputs on solving these? Thanks in advance.

1)
error C3861: '_beginthreadex': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h

_beginthreadex is defined in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\process.h, even after including this file, the same error is coming.

2) 
error C2664: 'ATL::ChTraitsOS::GetStringTypeExW' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'unsigned __int64 *' to 'LPWORD'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlstr.h

The following is definition of the function in the same file:
static BOOL GetStringTypeExW(
        *In* LCID lcid,
        *In* DWORD dwInfoType,
        _In_count_(nLength) LPCWSTR pszSrc,
        *In* int nLength,
        *Out* LPWORD pwCharType)

As these errors are related to Visual studio include files, I have tried changing project related settings, but nothing is working and the errors are still existing.

Comment: Don't pick and choose errors you like from the list.  Only the first few are really important.  You have to tackle those first.  Copy and paste from the Output window if you need help.

Comment: [@Hans] Thanks Hans. I am not able to paste the errors as it is in the comment part. But the above mentioned are the first errors.